# Cake on Ubuntu LAMP stack always sending <?php ?> in pages

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, ubuntu, lamp

I have a problem with my Cake application on Ubuntu 14.10. I try to see the source code from the page, it shows:

```
<?php
```

then the content shows after this tag.

This is a problem specially with AJAX request content, because this string appended breaks all the JavaScript.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
/**
 * Index
 *
 * The Front Controller for handling every request
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.webroot
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

/**
 * Use the DS to separate the directories in other defines
 */
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

/**
 * These defines should only be edited if you have cake installed in
 * a directory layout other than the way it is distributed.
 * When using custom settings be sure to use the DS and do not add a trailing DS.
 */

/**
 * The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}

/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}

/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 * Un-comment this line to specify a fixed path to CakePHP.
 * This should point at the directory containing `Cake`.
 *
 * For ease of development CakePHP uses PHP's include_path. If you
 * cannot modify your include_path set this value.
 *
 * Leaving this constant undefined will result in it being defined in Cake/bootstrap.php
 *
 * The following line differs from its sibling
 * /lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/webroot/index.php
 */
//define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');

/**
 * Editing below this line should NOT be necessary.
 * Change at your own risk.
 *
 */
if (!defined('WEBROOT_DIR')) {
    define('WEBROOT_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
}
if (!defined('WWW_ROOT')) {
    define('WWW_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
}

// for built-in server
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/' && file_exists(WWW_ROOT . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
        return false;
    }
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/' . basename(__FILE__);
}

if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
        ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
    }
    if (!include 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php') {
        $failed = true;
    }
} else {
    if (!include CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php') {
        $failed = true;
    }
}
if (!empty($failed)) {
    trigger_error("CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your " . DS . "cake core directory and your " . DS . "vendors root directory.", E_USER_ERROR);
}

App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');

$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$Dispatcher->dispatch(
    new CakeRequest(),
    new CakeResponse()
);
```

I try to found some solution to this but didn't find it.

Comment: Are you using a URL with a `.php` extension? Is there an .htaccess file involved to map URLs to files? Do ordinary PHP files work on this server?

Comment: No, i'm using CakePHP. Yes, has an .htaccess. The source code of htaccess and the index.php mapped is here: https://gist.github.com/lhas/d606fda8498de74ac14a It only happens with CakePHP apps, with ordinary PHP this didn't happen. I dont tried with another framework or CMS.

Comment: Is this with AJAX replies only, or all page requests? What code is rendered when this happens, your controller, your view/template? (If you feel code is appropriate to clarify this question, please add it into the question, rather than adding pasteboards - it makes it easier for new readers to understand the current state of the problem).

Comment: In all page requests this happens. AJAX or no. You can see a image [here](http://www.montagemfotos.com.br/tmp/1424557415311476.jpg?1424557415) It only shows in source code, in the render view not. Thanks for your observation.

Comment: Right, well I'll leave this for a Cake developer to look at. Last clarification though, has the front controller been modified from the default version? What are you doing differently that is not usually done in Cake applications?

Comment: (Your image is 404ing, please fix. Also please add an answer to this question above, which I think you missed: **What code is rendered when this happens, your controller, your view/template?**)

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Trusty Tahar ?